# How do I extract just a part of an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the result of an operation:

```
((t0M^2 + t1M^2)*xC/(2*t0M^2)
```

What is the best way to get just the $\frac{t0^2+t1^2}{2\space t0^2}$ from this expression? This value represents a factor that I'd like to use on other variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Coefficient[(t0M^2 + t1M^2)*xC/(2*t0M^2), xC]
```

> ```
> (t0M^2 + t1M^2)/(2 t0M^2)
> ```